# How to disable Google Analytics on 3G?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I would like to allow user to choose whether he/she allows my app to send Google Analytics data thru wi-fi only or thru wi-fi/3g. There are no according options in Google Analytics SDK. How could I implement the same myself?

Comment: Looks like I can disable automatic dispatch, then verify for internet connection type and send data manually - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/dispatch

Answer (score 0):

On the activity that you set Google Analytics, check if the device is running on Wifi or 3g (Or none)

```
NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) extras.getParcelable("networkInfo");
State networkState = info.getState();

if (networkState == State.CONNECTED) {
    if (info.getType() == TYPE_WIFI) {
        //Is on Wifi
    } else if (info.getType() == TYPE_MOBILE) { //Or similar
        //Is on 3G
    }   
}
```

After, on the lines you set Google Analytics, if there is no wifi connection, disable automatic dispatch by calling this instead of the regular start

```
mAnalyticsTracker.start("YOUR_UA", -1, this);
```

Remember the Permissions also

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```